# How To Import Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've imported an Android Studio project and the Module Settings screen is completely blank (it looks like it doesn't even render, there is no white box, it's just the grey background).  It shows SDK Location, Project, App, and Facebook (a dependency module) on the left but the right just looks like empty window.  It also tells me to specify an SDK and removes my ability to specify SDK 19 even though that's what the project should be set to. Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have a build.gradle file inside app folder?

Comment: Yes.  Thank you for the comment though.  When I open that file it says the "folder does not belong to a Gradle project" and to check settings.gradle but "app" is in settings.gradle (note that build.gradle exists in MyProject>app and another in MyProject>facebook and settings.gradle exists in MyProject itself).

Comment: settings.gradle is outside the folder app, and its only content is: include ':app'

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help you further